# Magento 1.9 : 404 Error Page not found for configruation

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, system.xml

I created system xml and configuration tab but it shows 404 error. Any hint?

Comment: Please  add your system.xml  and other details if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have set ACL roles for your config section, somethink like this:

> .../etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <my_tab translate="title" module="my_module">
                                        <title>Tab label</title>
                                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                    </my_tab>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                 </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

First try to log out of Magento and log back in